# how to set logo.jpg(image) to login page exclusively

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i am working on one application which displays the logo.jpg(image) in every page.I want to restrict this image to only login page.Not to the main menu(which navigates after login) and the remaining pages too.
My login is Jsp page. I changed the css,loginSession.jsp but doesnt show any difference.Is it possible to do any changes to make visible(logo.jpg) at login page only.? My application source code is opengts(latest version).I have been making changes to get my desired result.Please need suggestions and help.If any working on the opengts..kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in the JSP - something like THIS (I have never used GTS)

```
<gts:var ifKey="pageTitle" compare="eq" value="Login">
  <img src="logo.jpg" />
</gts:var>
```

or

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  if (location.href.indexOf('login.jsp')!=-1) {  
    document.getElementById('logo').style.display="";
  }
}
</script>

.
.
.
<img src="logo.jpg" id="logo" style="display:none" />
```

Comment: @mplungjan..thanks a lot for ur reply...will it possible to change in jsp file..if so..please below file is the loginsession_banner.jsp

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/Track.tld" prefix="gts" %>
<%@ page isELIgnored="true" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%
response.setHeader("CACHE-CONTROL", "NO-CACHE");
response.setHeader("PRAGMA"       , "NO-CACHE");
response.setDateHeader("EXPIRES"  , 0         );
%>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> -->
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'>
<!-- loginSession_banner.jsp
  -->
<gts:var ifKey="notDefined" value="true">
<!--
  See "logSession.jsp" for additional notes
  -->
</gts:var>

Comment: <!-- Head -->
<head>
  <!-- meta -->
  <gts:var>
  <meta name="author" content="GeoTelematic Solutions, Inc."/>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content='no-cache'/>
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
  <meta name="copyright" content="${copyright}"/>
  <meta name="robots" content="none"/>
  </gts:var>
  <!-- page title -->
  <gts:var>
  <title>${pageTitle}</title>
  </gts:var>

Comment: <!-- default style -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/General.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/MenuBar.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/Controls.css'/>
  <!-- custom overrides style -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='custom/General.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='custom/MenuBar.css'/>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='custom/Controls.css'/>

Comment: <!-- javascript -->
  <script src="./js/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <gts:track section="javascript"/>
  <!-- local style -->
  <style type="text/css">
    BODY { 
        background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    }
    TD.titleText {
        /* background: #DBDEEB url('./images/Banner_White90.png') center no-repeat; */
         background: #FFFFFF url('./images/Banner_WhiteShadow.png') center no-repeat;
        font-family: arial,verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 28pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        color: #000000;
    }
  </style>

Comment: </style>
  <!-- page specific style -->
  <gts:track section="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- custom override style -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='custom/Custom.css'/>
</head>
<body onLoad="<gts:track section='body.onload'/>" onUnload="<gts:track section='body.onunload'/>">
<table width="100%" height="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-top: 5px;">
<tbody>

Comment: <tr>
  <td width="100%">
    <table class="bannerTable" width="860" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <gts:var>  
       <td width="860" height="120" halign="center">
          <div align="center"><img src="./images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="1000" height="300">
          </div>
          </td>
        </gts:var>  
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="center">
     <table width="100" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tbody>
     <tr>

Comment: <%--   <td class="navBarClear" nowrap align="left">&nbsp;<gts:var ifKey="isLoggedIn" value="true"><i>${i18n.Account}:</i> ${accountDesc} (${userDesc})           </gts:var></td>
         <td class="navBarClear" nowrap align="right" width="100%"><gts:var>&nbsp;${navigation}&nbsp;&nbsp;</gts:var></td>--%>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
  </td>
  </tr>

Comment: <tr height="100%">
  <td>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td valign='top' align='center' height='100%'>
           <table class="<gts:track section='content.class.table'/>" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
           <tbody>
              <!-- The MenuBar is display iff 'content.class.table' is "contentTable"/"contentMapTable" -->
              <tr><gts:track section="content.menubar"/></tr>
              <tr height='100%'>

Comment: <td class="<gts:track section='content.class.cell'/>">
                    <gts:track section="content.body"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="<gts:track section='content.id.message'/>" class="<gts:track section='content.class.message'/>">
                    <gts:track section="content.message"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
           </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  </tr>

Comment: <!-- Begin Page footer ======================================== -->
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: 7pt; border-bottom: 1px solid #888888;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <table class="copyrightFooterClear" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0px 0px 2px 5px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="100%">
         &nbsp;

Comment: </td>
      <td nowrap style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
         <span style="font-size: 7pt; font-style: oblique; color: #888888;">
             <gts:var ifKey="login.showGTSVersion" compare="ne" value="false">${version}</gts:var>
         </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<gts:var ifKey="login.showPiLink" compare="ne" value="false"><a style="font-size: 11pt; text-decoration: none;" href="${login.piLink=http://www.opengts.org}" target="_blank">&pi;</a>&nbsp;</gts:var>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  </tr>

Comment: <!-- End Page footer ======================================== -->
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
<!-- ======================================================================================= -->
</html>

Comment: @Hari, please see update. Next time just edit your question and add as code. What you pasted here is unreadable

Comment: @mplungjan .Hi sir, i changed the jsp code with ur jsp(mentioned above) and also disabled the div tag in the above code. if i disable the div tag of img src,the logo will not appear at login page too.but ur replies helped me a lot...